# How can I switch JSON eventSource on-fly?

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using JSON event source in my code. How can I switch 'evenDatasource' on existing calendar? Idea behind is to add switch to page to allow user to select calendar data source without the reload. I just need to switch eventSource on-fly. How can I do it?

> $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
>
> ```
> eventSources: [
>
>     // your event source
>     {
>         url: '/myfeed.php', // use the `url` property
>         color: 'yellow',    // an option!
>         textColor: 'black'  // an option!
>     }
>
>     // any other sources...
>
> ]
> ```
>
> });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [events as functions](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/). If your switch calls
`.fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' )` on change and your event function reads what events to fetch from the switch you should be fine.